# How do I simplify a circuit with connecting wires in it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

In the given network, I am asked to find the equivalent resistance across the terminals. Given, the voltage supply across A and B is $V$ volts. When I tried to simplify the given network, I ended up connecting the resistor $P$ in parallel with an equivalent resistance of $\frac{3R}{2}$. The final answer that I got matched the original answer which is,  $\frac{3R}{5}$. But, my professor says that my simplified network diagram is wrong. Can someone explain how to simplify this network?

Note: $P$ denotes a resistor of resistance $R$ ( top left).
Final Answer: $\frac{3R}{5}$

Comment: Isn't that middle resistor become redundant? Current follows least resistance path so after passing through first resistor (bottom) current should pass through just wire not those two resistors. Then resistor P and third resistor (bottom) will in be in series so add up (R + R = 2R) and as in whole parallel with first resistor (bottom). So, total resistance equals ((1/2R) + (1/R))^-1= 2R/3 ohm. I don't know if I'm correct or not but this is what I thought.

Comment: you are talking about short circuit. That happens only when both the ends of a combination of resistance is connected by a connecting wire and this connecting wire is in turn connected to a power source.

Comment: @learner no, the second resistor (bottom) is in parallel with the third one.

Comment: Please show your simplified network diagram.

Comment: bhuvanesh and @fqq Okay thanks for guiding me. bhuvanesh Can you share the name of book from which this question is taken

Comment: This question is a very standard one. It can be found in almost every engineering entrance books from india. If you're looking for more such problems, go for "HC VERMA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one possibility for the circuit drawing,
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to color-code the nodes in the circuit, like this:

[image]

(I've also numbered the individual resistors so we can talk about them clearly)

After doing that, it's easier to see that R3 and R4 are in parallel, for example.

Then it's easier to work out a clearer drawing of the circuit, like this:

[image]

Comment: i ended up connecting R2 and (R3, R4) in series. These together in parallel with R1. Im getting confused. Can you explain a little more on how to join the ends?

Comment: @bhuvanesh, First, let's call the node I colored green, "C". Now look at the original schematic. R1 connects between node A and node C.  R2 connects between node A and node B. and so on. If you connected R2 between A and C instead, then your new "simplified" schematic just doesn't match the original.

Comment: I see that two wires join together at the end of both the terminals. So, should i just draw them first?

Comment: You should name your nodes, and make sure each resistor connects between the same two nodes as it did in the original schematic. The whole point of this exercise is that whether the node wires are drawn branching or straight doesn't matter --- only whether the same resistors are connected to the same nodes.

Comment: yeah, i understand. But the problem is, i get confused when wiring the combinations in parallel.

Comment: So check your work: Check each resistor. Does it connect to the same nodes it did in the original? If it does, then you haven't changed the circuit. If it doesn't, then you messed up.

Comment: got it. But having too many nodes will create confusion, right

Comment: There are three nodes in this circuit. If your "simplification" has any more or less than that, then it isn't the same circuit.

Comment: should i consider those points that have 2 or more interconnection as nodes or 3 or more interconnections as nodes?

Comment: This is not a discussion site. If you have more questions, you should ask them as new questions. (Some of your questions might be better on the electronics site than physics)